Error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.'
I got this error message when I tried to debug my web project:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.'

I have some files to show:

Program.cs:

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication1.Data;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 7152, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps();
        listenOptions.Protocols = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
    });
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

// Configure CORS
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", policy =>
    {
        policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
              .AllowAnyMethod()
              .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddDbContext<FlightBookingDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("FlightBookingDbContext")));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseCors("AllowAll");

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Homepage}/{id?}");

app.Run();


appsettings.json:

{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",


  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "FlightBookingDbContext": "Server=.;Database=WebProject;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }

}


AirportService.cs:

using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

public class AirportService
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public AirportService(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> GetAirports()
    {
        var airports = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Airport", connection);
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var airport = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "Name", reader["name"].ToString() },
                    { "Location", reader["location"].ToString() },
                    { "IATACode", reader["iata_code"].ToString() },
                    { "ICAOCode", reader["icao_code"].ToString() },
                    { "Type", reader["type"].ToString() }
                };

                airports.Add(airport);
            }
        }

        return airports;
    }
}


AirportController.cs:

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AirportController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly AirportService _airportService;

    public AirportController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _airportService = new AirportService(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var airports = _airportService.GetAirports();
        return Ok(airports);
    }
}


site.js:

async function fetchAirports() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://localhost:7152/api/Airport');
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        }

        const airports = await response.json();
        displayAirports(airports);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch airports:', error);
        alert('Có lỗi xảy ra khi lấy danh sách sân bay.');
    }
}

function displayAirports(airports) {
    const airportTableBody = document.getElementById('airportTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    airportTableBody.innerHTML = '';

    airports.forEach(airport => {
        const row = airportTableBody.insertRow();
        row.insertCell(0).textContent = airport.name;
        row.insertCell(1).textContent = airport.location;
        row.insertCell(2).textContent = airport.iata_code;
        row.insertCell(3).textContent = airport.icao_code;
        row.insertCell(4).textContent = airport.type;
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    fetchAirports();
});

I have 2 web pages, Homepage and AirportDetail. In Homepage, I have a Airport to direct to page AirportDetail. However, the server said:

localhost:7125 said "Có lỗi xảy ra khi lấy danh sách sân bay."


Do we need all of that code? I suggest taking the time to make a [mre] (with emphasis on minimal).

Why aren't you using dependency injection?

And why pass the connection string in, why not access it directly in your service?

In the AirportController constructor, change the string from DefaultConnection to FlightBookingDbContext, because your appsettings.json file has connection named FlightBookingDbContext
